# France Long Term Study visa after tourist visa

Tags: visas, schengen, france, study

I'm an Aussie planning on going to Paris and to look around and become more familiar with the language, and am considering applying to a university there afterwards - whether for further language studies, or to continue my degree.

I've searched and haven't found the answer to this specific situation - if I stay in Paris for <90 days, am I able to then go back to Australia at the end of that period and apply for a long term student visa? My main concern is the 90/180 rule for the Schengen Area. I've seen one source that says changing visa status resets it, but i don't want to take any risks and would love a confirmation and/or further information.

Edit: Does this also hold true for the long stay visitor visa?

Comment: Student visas are issued under a different regime than Schengen visas. What you propose to do sounds fine and there is no reason to expect problems with the 90/180 rule because that's a Schengen thing and not applicable to an application for a student visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a French D national visa, then time *in France* does not count against the Schengen 90/180 rule. Time in other Schengen states still does. So if you cut it really close there might be some problem if you want to fly e.g. through Frankfurt or Amsterdam.

---

Follow-Up: [REGULATION (EU) 2016/399 OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32016R0399&from=EN), paragraph 6, section 2.

Comment: Actually a holder of a valid long-stay visa is allowed to _transit_ through other Schengen states on thrie way to the issuing state, even though they may not have days left on their Schengen clock -- see article 6.5(a) of the Border Code.

Comment: Thank you @o.m. ! I should have put this in my original question, and i don't want to clog up the exchange with near-redundant questions, but i wonder if you'd know whether the same holds true for the French long stay visitor visa?

Comment: @Roger, article 6 seems pretty clear when it comes to 90/180 and **other** Schengen states. "Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States."